# Bash script for multiple tabs program running

Tags: command-line, bash

I have the following bash script code to open multiple session of a python script with different input argument in different terminal tabs.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/me/experiment

tab=" --tab-with-profile=Default"
options=()  #(--tab --title=Terminal)

cmds[1]="./new_path.py -s 593000 -f 593200"
titles[1]="0593000_0593200"

cmds[2]="./new_path.py -s 593200 -f 593400"
titles[2]="0593200_0593400"

cmds[3]="./new_path.py -s 593400 -f 593600"
titles[3]="0593400_0593600"

cmds[4]="./new_path.py -s 593600 -f 593800"
titles[4]="0593600_0593800"

cmds[5]="./new_path.py -s 593800 -f 594000"
titles[5]="0593800_0594000"



for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
  options+=($tab --title="${titles[i]}"  -e "bash -c \"${cmds[i]} ; bash\"" )          
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"


exit 0
```

How can I avoid typing the same command multiple times using for loop and bash script variable?

Comment: If this is something you need to do regularly, it might be worth your while to have a look at tmux or gnu screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shorten your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/me/experiment

args=()
for ((step=200, s=593000; (f=s+step)<=594000; s+=step)); do
    cmd="./new_path.py -s $s -f $f";  printf -v title '%07d_%07d' $s $f
    args+=(--tab-with-profile=Default -t $title -e "sh -c \"$cmd; bash\"")
done

gnome-terminal "${args[@]}"
```

To eliminate repetition, I got rid of the `cmds` and `titles` arrays altogether and **moved construction of those strings into the loop, where it could be automated.**

<sup>I did test this of course; though in my test I used `mate-terminal` instead of `gnome-terminal`. They are very similar, `mate-terminal` being a fork of `gnome-terminal`, and I'd be quite surprised if any problems arose from that difference; `mate-terminal`'s features are a subset of those provided by `gnome-terminal`. Most importantly, both accept the same `--tab-with-profile`, `-t`, and `-e` options.</sup>

A more detailed explanation of how the above code works, and why  chose that implementation, follows, in case you're interested.

---

Instead of looping over the sequence `1 2 3 4 5`, which is meaningless to the problem, I made the loop variable `s`, the value passed to `./new_path.py` after `-s`. I also defined `f` and ensured it took on a value 200 greater than `s` in each iteration of the loop; this is the value passed to `./new_path.py` after `-f`.

That made it easy to construct each iteration's `cmd` and `title` strings. (`cmd` is the value passed to `gnome-terminal` after `-e`, and `title` is the value passed after `-t`.)

- Making `cmd` was particularly simple. `s` and `f` could just appear in the string without modification, dereferenced as `$s` and `$f` within the double-quoted expression.
- For `title` I noticed the leading zeros in your manually written strings (e.g., `"0593000_0593200"`). I inferred you probably want the title numbers zero-padded whenever they're fewer than seven digits, and used bash's `printf` [builtin](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) to achieve this.

There were several possible constructions to choose from, in writing the loop. In addition to the more common `for variable in list` syntax, bash supports C-style `for` with `(( initialization; condition; increment-or-other-action))` syntax, which I decided to use.

My goals in deciding how to write the loop included:

- making it so that when the loop is modified later, each number can be changed in just one place (e.g., avoiding having `200` appear multiple times in the code), *and*
- reflecting the logic of the underlying problem being solved.

In bash, sequences of numbers are usually best generated with `{start..end..step}` (or just `{start..end}` for contiguous sequences). But [brace expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is performed before [shell parameter expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), so *`start`*, *`end`*, and *`step`* cannot be variables (like `$step`).

A `for s in seq 593000 593800 $step` loop (and setting `f=$((s+step))` inside the loop) would've worked for this, and I would probably have done it that way if easy code maintenance were my only concern.

Based on your original script, it seems the underlying problem being solved is, or is *something like*, this:

- Perform runs (of some experiment or calculation).
- Vary some important parameter, whose starting and final values are specified to `./new_path.py` via `-s` and `-f`.
- The important parameter ranges from 593000 to 594000.
- Vary sequentially in chunks of 200. Cover the range by running five such tasks in parallel.

This suggested it would be valuable to write the loop in such a way that the *lowest `-s` value* and *highest `-f` value* were specified (rather than the lowest and highest `-s` values). I used a C-style `for ((...))` loop, which facilitated that in a reasonably concise and readable way.

*Note that this was not the only way to do it, nor is there any one "Right Way." In particular, I could've instead defined `step` and `max` (and initialized `s` to its minimum value) before the loop, then used a while loop with arithmetic comparison (via [`((`](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) with `<=`, or [`[[`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/test.1posix.html) with `-le`) in the condition.*

I made a few other changes, compared to your original script, by they are minor and entirely a matter of stylistic preference.

- I renamed `options` to `args` because "options" is often used specifically to mean flags (such as those starting with `-` and `--`) rather than all command-line arguments.
- Since the `+=` operator is being used to build an array of arguments rather than the final command string itself, no leading or trailing whitespace is needed in its elements. So I removed the leading space before `--tab-with-profile`.
- In the flags passed to [`gnome-terminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html), I changed `--title` to `-t` for consistency with the choice of `-e`. (`-t` is the short form of `--title=`; `-e` is the short form of `--command=`.) This also made it a little easier to read because it let `$title` be a separate array element instead of having to be combined into a string as `"--title=$title"`.
- I used `sh -c ...` instead of `bash -c ...` as the command passed to `gnome-terminal`, since the generic [`sh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sh.1posix.html) (which in Ubuntu is the simpler, lighter weight [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dash.1.html)) is sufficient to the task of chaining two simple commands with `;`. (I *didn't* change the `bash` after `;` to `sh`, because the interactive shell that runs in each tab after `./new_path.py` finishes should of course still be bash.)

  In this context, this is definitely *not* a performance consideration, but just a matter of style. I am *not* suggesting that using `sh -c` instead of `bash -c` for this is the *right* way or that it is objectively preferable.